# Docker Compose mysql import .sql

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm having trouble importing an .sql dump file with docker-compose. I've followed the docs, which apparently will load the .sql file from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. However, when I run `docker-compose up`, the sql file is not copied over to the container.

I've tried stopping the containers with `-vf` flag, but that didn't work either. Am I doing something wrong in my .yml script?

I have dump.sql in the directory database/db-dump/ in the root where my compose file is.

```
frontend:
  image: myimage
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  links:
   - mysql
mysql:
  image: mysql
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
    MYSQL_USER: dbuser
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: userpass
    MYSQL_DATABASE: myimage_db
  volumes:
   - ./database/db-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: Your docker-compose is working on my machine. Attach please dir structure of your dump location on host, and how you are checking what file was copied to container.

Comment: The dir structure is "database > db-dump > dump.sql" once the compose is up a conect to the mysql container and check the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d dir which is always empty

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After many attempts with the volumes setting i found a workaround

I created another image based on mysql with the following in the Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:5.6

ADD dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Then removed the volumes from compose and ran the new image

```
frontend:
  image: myimage
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  links:
   - mysql
mysql:
  image: mymysql
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
    MYSQL_USER: dbuser
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: userpass
    MYSQL_DATABASE: myimage_db
```

This way the dump is always copied over and run on startup

Comment: You should take a look at : https://gist.github.com/spalladino/6d981f7b33f6e0afe6bb

Comment: Wait, there's no reason to build a new image just to import some files: it would make sense only if that data is never changing, and you're sharing the image to your collegues, so they don't need to import the file everytime. But for normal cases, using volumes is the solution to adopt.

Answer (score 76):

This worked for me,

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ecommerce

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

mysql-dump must be a directory. All the .sql's in the directory will be imported.

Comment: remember, your SQL statement may need `CREATE DATABASE [name]` and `USE [name]` statements, you can confirm your SQL file will work with `docker exec -i [container_id] sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"[password]"' < /path/to/db/files/dump.sql`, if it works here it should work in your docker-compose file

Comment: If the `db` container is already built, `docker compose up` may not reflect the entrypoint addition. Do a `docker compose down` do delete all containers first

Answer (score 26):

This appears on the documentation page of Docker MySQL image: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

> **Initializing a fresh instance**
>
> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions `.sh`, `.sql` and `.sql.gz` that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. You can easily populate your mysql services by [mounting a SQL
>   dump into that
>   directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume)
>   and provide [custom
>   images](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable.

Comment: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d is only read at container creation. And OP was asking for a database "update" when he run docker-compose up.

Answer (score 20):

Mysql database dump **schema.sql** is residing in the **/mysql-dump/schema.sql** directory and it creates tables during the initialization process.

docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --user=root
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue with mysql where I would mount a local directory at /configs/mysql/data containing a mydatabasedump.sql file via docker-compose to the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d volume,
the file would get loaded on to the container but not execute or populate the database when the container initialized. My intial docker-compose.yml looke like this:

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        build: ./build/mysql/ #this is pointing to my Dockerfile
        container_name: MYSQL_Database
        restart: always
        environment:
        MYSQL_PORT: 3306
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
        MYSQL_DATABASE: my_app_database
        MYSQL_USER: admin
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
        - ./configs/mysql/data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:
```

I found two working solutions for this problem:

The first came after I logged in the running container and confirmed that mydatabasedump.sq file was present and executable in the container's docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory; I created and added 
a bash script to my local /configs/mysql/data directory called dump.sh that excuted after the container was initialized. It contains a single mysql command that copies my_database_dump.sql  to my_app_database.
The bash script looks like this

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #dump.sh
    mysql -uadmin -padmin my_app_database < my_database_dump.sql 
    #end of dump.sh
```

I executed this script via my Dockerfile in the ENTRYPOINT directive like this:

```
    #Dockerfile
    FROM mysql:5.5
    ENTRYPOINT [ "dump.sh" ]
    EXPOSE 80
    #end of Dockerfile
```

After realizing the initial issue was due to the volumes being mouted after the cotainer is built and therefore not intilizing the database with the dump file (or executing any scripts in that directory) at boot time, the second solution was simply to
move the volumes directive in my compose-file above the built directive. This worked and allowed me to remove the dump.sh scrip and the DOCKERENTRY directive in my Dockerfile. 
The modified docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        volumes:
          - ./configs/mysql/data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
       build: ./build/mysql/ #this is pointing to my Dockerfile
         container_name: MYSQL_Database
         restart: always
     environment:
         MYSQL_PORT: 3306
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
         MYSQL_DATABASE: my_app_database
         MYSQL_USER: admin
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
```

Comment: Thank you! This has helped in my case while the others didn't.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to keep the original setup of the container, so I tried a restore on the already running container. This seemed to work:

```
cat dump.sql | docker-compose exec -T db mysql -h localhost -u root -psomewordpress -v
```

But it was very slow and the verbose output seemed to be buffered, so I tried:

```
docker-compose cp dump.sql db:/tmp/
docker-compose exec db sh -c "mysql -h localhost -u root -psomewordpress -v < /tmp/dump.sql"
```

Which at least provided faster feedback.

Might be useful for someone? Looks like it was mainly slow because I used `--skip-extended-insert` on the dump, without the extended inserts it went faster

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem. I mount a local directory at ./mysql-dump containing a init.sql file via docker-compose to the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d volume, the file would get loaded on to the container but not execute or populate the database when the container initialized.
My intial docker-compose.yml looke like this:

```js
mysqld:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysqld
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=fendou
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
             --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

but it doesn't work for me.
I found another working solutions for this problem:
add `--init-file /data/application/init.sql` to mysql command.change above configuration like

```js
mysqld:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysqld
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
      # - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=fendou
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
             --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
             --init-file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql  #attention here
```

hope it help for you